# Replace host variables in Jijnja template file in ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I need to replace a file with the variables defined in the host file.

- Following is the host variables defined in "host_vars/abc.1234.com"

```
env: acc
abcserverName:
  -  name: abc1
  -  name: abc2
```

- The playbook file has the following contents

```
 - hosts: "abc.1234.com"
  become: yes
  tasks:
 - name: deploy abc control file
     template:
       src: abc-control.j2
       dest: /etc/init.d/{{ env }}-{{ item.name }}
     with_items:
       - "{{ abcservername }}"
 - name: start abcserver
    command: /etc/init.d/control-{{ env }}-{{ item.name }}  start
    with_items:
      - "{{ abcserverName }}"
```

This will copy 2 files in init.d, which is the following:

```
/etc/init.d/control-acc-abc1
/etc/init.d/control-acc-abc2
```

**Requirement**:

Inside each of the above control files, I also need to get the correct "abcserverName"

For example in "/etc/init.d/control-acc-abc1", I want

```
SERVER_NAME=abc1
```

and  in For example in "/etc/init.d/control-acc-abc2"

```
SERVER_NAME=abc2
```

I don't have much knowledge about jinja templates and google shows me complex examples. Any help to achieve this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this jinja2 code for example:

```
SERVER_NAME={{ server_name }}
```

`server_name` is not actually defined, and to use it you will need to pass it as a variable to your template.

Using your task:

```
- name: deploy abc control file
 template:
   src: abc-control.j2
   dest: /etc/init.d/{{ env }}-{{ item.name }}
 with_items:
   - "{{ abcservername }}" 
 vars:
   server_name: {{ item.name }}
```

Now "control-acc-abc1" will have server_name set to abc1 and "control-acc-abc2" will have server_name set to abc2